# (PHP) Session login via url

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, authentication

I once saw a friends site, which allowed you to see a private php file by browsing to a url.

So for example, http://example.com/accessthesite.php would then show you the content that is hidden on http://example.com/index.php

They basically used it for previewing changes to their site as it hadn't launched fully.

So whilst /index.php had a coming soon page up, if you browsed to /accessthesite.php you would then be redirected to /index.php and shown the full website.

Any idea's how they did this?

Comment: You could pass some POST variables to authenticate, use php session variables, or other means. Basically turning accessthesite.php into a primer which sets up some access variable that index.php reads and grants access for.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that accessthesite.php set a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), or a [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php). Once set, index.php contains code to recognize this and display an alternate view.

I have used this method myself for various thing, but I often times find it easier to setup a second development and/or staging site. Pending changes can be viewed there before they are published to the public site. In general, it's not a good idea for developers to be working directly on the public site since there might be problems. You do not want to inconvenience users by displaying a site that isn't ready yet.